# Delta Leland Kitchen Faucet Removal

Tags: kitchens, faucet, plumbing-fixture

I am trying to remove a Delta Leland Kitchen Faucet.
[image: Kitchen Faucet[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxURm.jpg)
When I try to loosen the bolt from the bottom of the sink, the entire fixture spins.  I can't get any leverage to turn the bolt.  If I have someone while hole the faucet and I turn the bolt, it still spins.
Any way to got this off with out using a grinder?  There is a little bit of space at the base of the faucet, so would prying off the fixture be an option? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That thing is so hopelessly corroded that the only hope I see is to use one of the following:

[image]

*<sup>(Picture Source: https://www.dremeleurope.com/general/en/cut-offwheel32mm-184-ocs-p/)</sup>*

[image]

*<sup>(Picture Source: [https://www.amazon.com/Stanley-Hand-Tools-20-807-Mini-HackTM/dp/B00009OYGD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009OYGD))</sup>*

Any type of hammering, prying, twisting or chiseling you try to do is liable to either bend/break your sink or damage the finish if it is a porcelain type sink.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I was thinking.  Do you think a hack saw could cut through that metal thread?

Comment: @DIYNewbie - Sure it will cut the metal......slowly. The Dremel with cutoff disk may be a better choice though. A lot less wear and tear on the old knuckles.

Comment: Is there a high quality hack saw that you would recommend?  I want to make sure I get as little wear and tear on the knuckles :) Thanks for your help!