# Where do I find a wrench for this nut?

Tags: faucet

This nut secures the kitchen sink faucet to the sink.  I am not sure the size of it.

It is also difficult to get to it.   It is thin and looks quite recesed in.
Is there a special tool for it to help me remove the nut.

I tried taking off the nut, underneath the faucet and failed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you would need the model number of a faucet that you are replacing.

Comment: Do you need the model of the faucet you're removing, or do you need to know how to take the faucet off the counter? If you'll [edit] in a couple of pictures of the problem area, we can help you get the faucet removed. (Hint: look for a "basin wrench" at your local home center - that's the kind of tool you'll likely need.)

Comment: Take the picture to a hardware store or home center and they should be able to immediately hand you the proper tool.

Comment: @Alex Z, I edited your post so those who don't understand what you are asking will get it.  In the meantime just google this:  " plumbers drain wrench". " undersink nut wrench". And you will find choice of wrench galore.  Choose the one that suits your need.  You will recognize it when you see it.   No problems.   You take care.

Comment: @Alex Z,  Here is my editing of your post, since they closed it.   There is no guarantee they will open your post.  It is the way it is, nothing you and I can do about it.. :  This nut secures the kitchen sink faucet to the sink. I am not sure the size of it.

It is also difficult to get to it. It is thin and looks quite recesed in. Is there a special tool for it to help me remove the nut.

I tried taking off the nut, underneath the faucet and failed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @FreeMan, The individual clearly asking for help how to remove the nut.  He wasn't able to remove it with the tool he had for obvious reasons.  It is a thin recessed in nut.  He is not asking for someone to help locate the make and model of the faucet.  I edited the question and perhaps my editing isn't clear enough either.

Comment: @Meta_Alchemy the OP VERY CLEARLY (in all-caps) asked for the model number in the original question, then that part got edited out _after_ my comment. You can click the `edited <x time> ago` text above the most recent editor's name to see the full edit history. Also, I did help the OP by giving a hint as to what tool is needed to remove the nut. Good, clear communication is difficult (ask my wife of 32 years) and the ability for people to do so is going down the toilet because no one expects it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

That's a Delta, as also [shown here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/154052/delta-leland-kitchen-faucet-removal). Normally, you just unscrew it by hand with the black plastic part which acts as a wrench around the metallic nut.

They were already removed in the picture but you must first loosen the two screws which prevent it from rotating. It's possible the screws were never installed and the nut was screwed on too tight instead. In that case, good luck. You'll need creative application of force.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a basin wrench or a faucet installation tool or as some call it a faucet change out tool. I recommend the faucet installation tool. Tho both can be picked up at your local hardware store. The installation tool is super handy to have around.

- https://www.lowes.com/pd/Kobalt-Basin-Wrench/1002645186
- https://www.lowes.com/pd/Kobalt-Faucet-Change-Out-Tool/1002797772

Hope it helps and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have this wide adjustable wrench just for jobs like this, when the nut is hard to reach.

[image]